# Incorrect syntax near ')' SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find data of One Table where Weeks column is greater than result of Subquery.But somehow that is not running due to Incorrect syntax

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 a WHERE CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(a.WEEKS,CHARINDEX('W/E',WEEKS)+4,12),1)>
(SELECT MAX(x.WEEKS) AS MONTHLY_MAX_WEEKS FROM
(
(SELECT MAX(CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(WEEKS,CHARINDEX('W/E',WEEKS)+4,12),1)) AS WEEKS  FROM Table2 
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(WEEKS,CHARINDEX('W/E',WEEKS)+4,12),1)) AS WEEKS FROM Table3 
) AS x))
```

Comment: You already have a solution, but for situations like this, try breaking down and running each part of your query separately first to see if they run.  That can help track down the error.  Then start combining them slowly to find the error.  This approach works good for testing logic as well, test each part FIRST then combine them.

Comment: Do you *really* need a subquery with a subquery in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change like this

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 a WHERE CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(a.WEEKS,CHARINDEX('W/E',WEEKS)+4,12),1)>
(
SELECT MAX(x.WEEKS) AS MONTHLY_MAX_WEEKS 
FROM
(
  (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(WEEKS,CHARINDEX('W/E',WEEKS)+4,12),1)) AS WEEKS  FROM Table2 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX(CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(WEEKS,CHARINDEX('W/E',WEEKS)+4,12),1)) AS WEEKS FROM Table3 
  ) 
)as x
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should  remove some  AS

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 a 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(a.WEEKS,CHARINDEX('W/E',WEEKS)+4,12),1) >
(SELECT MAX(x.WEEKS) AS MONTHLY_MAX_WEEKS 
    FROM (
    SELECT MAX(CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(WEEKS,CHARINDEX('W/E',WEEKS)+4,12),1)) AS WEEKS  FROM Table2 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(WEEKS,CHARINDEX('W/E',WEEKS)+4,12),1)) AS WEEKS FROM Table3 
) t  )
```